# Time series forecasting with hour data, prediction for next 24 hours

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, trend, multiple-seasonalities

i'm a newbie in Time Series Analysis. I have a 2 year pandas dataframe about water consumptions in hour granularity (24 records for day, 365 days).

```
                            Water_consumptions
Data                                     
2017-01-01 00:00:00            315.546173
2017-01-01 01:00:00            322.469203
2017-01-01 02:00:00            305.497974
2017-01-01 03:00:00            291.905637
2017-01-01 04:00:00            268.990071
2017-01-01 05:00:00            267.545479 
                 ...
```

I would like to **predict day water consumptions (the next 24 records)** based on this two years. Which kind of model is most accurate for this task?

I've read about Sarimax and Recurrent Neural Network (LSTM) as a possibility. Are there other possibilities?

My series has also trending and seasonal component. Have my series to be stationarized? Why? in which way i have to use trending, seasonal and residuals in my model after my series was stationarized? i think i can't remove annual seasonality with 2 only years of data:

Plotting before stationarity:

[image]

Plotting after stationarity, except for annual seasonality:
[image: ****]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You very probably have [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities): intra-daily, intra-weekly and intra-yearly. Therefore, my first choice would be models that explicitly address these. Examples of such models are [bats](/questions/tagged/bats) and [tbats](/questions/tagged/tbats). Both are available in the `forecast` package for R (beware: they take a long time to fit), but I am not aware of any implementations for Python.

Seasonal ARIMA can only deal with a single seasonality. You could (and should) certainly fit this as a benchmark, separately for the three kinds of seasonality your data probably contains.

That said, both years of your history exhibit a marked dip around August, but the dips are different in both years. Even if this is apparently not the focal time period for your forecast, [it would be good to understand what actually happened here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222189/1352) and perhaps to model it in some way, e.g., by regressing your consumption on dummy variables and then applying a time series model to residuals.

Comment: +1. Also: two years is not very much data in terms of yearly seasonal patterns. You're trying to predict something you've only seen twice.

Comment: Looks like there is a tbats and bats implementation for Python: https://github.com/intive-DataScience/tbats

Answer (score 0):

[Forecasting data with multiple seasonality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399570/forecasting-data-with-multiple-seasonality/399590#399590) raises a similar question. My response is that there may be latent deterministic factors which should be taken into account in addition to short-term memory. I have found that 3-4 years of daily data should be used BUT if 2 years is all that is available you might be able to pick up some holiday effects.